# Using AES with the same output

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

I have a little background of cryptography so forgive me if this is a silly question. Is there a secure way to encrypt a text using AES that produces the same output with the same input?

### Edit

What i want is to store emails in a external analytics provider using AES256 or HMAC 256 (this is a company requirement). But i need to be able to decipher them lately and to distinguish between same emails without deciphering them. I know i can do this with two entries, one with AES and another using HMAC. But can i do this with AES alone and still be secure?

Comment: Seems like an [X-Y](http://xyproblem.info/) problem. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: ok, you are right, im editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. There is a mode called [ECB,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#ECB) "electronic code book", that will always produce the same output (cipher text) for a given input (plain text) block.

However, unless you only send each plain text block one time, ECB is not secure. At first, an adversary who intercepts an encrypted message won't be able to decipher it. But, just like old time code books, as they continue to monitor encrypted messages and combine that with knowledge of the context in which they were sent, they can eventually break much of your code.

Use of ECB is generally discouraged. For most messaging applications, an [AEAD mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) like GCM is recommended.

Comment: so for my current situation GCM is the way to go? Thanks :)

Comment: GCM still relies on an IV which is (supposed) to change with each invoke.  I don't recall offhand if the IV goes into the tag calculation, but if it does, this wouldn't really meet OPs requirement of being able to compare either the cipher or tag produced by GCM to see if two messages were "the same" without decrypting.  Also I don't really understand what OP is trying to accomplish, so maybe this comment is way off base :)

Comment: @7daysofrain Sorry, I gave this answer before you edited your question and the advice to use GCM probably won't work in your case. Your update is still a little unclear: how will an external analytics provider do anything with the message if it is encrypted? And, it's not clear where the duplicate emails are coming from. Do you mean that you'd store multiple copies of an email in the external provider? Or are you checking whether a local email is already in the external provider?